# Oracle count sub types group by sub type along with main type

Tags: oracle, group-by

My Table Structure

```
Id| Sub_Type| Main_Type
---|------- | -------
1  | high   | c1
2  | low    | c1
3  | high   | c1
4  | low    | c1
5  | high   | c2
6  | low    | c2
```

Expected result

```
count|Sub_Type|Main_Type
-----|------- |---------
2    | high   |  c1
2    |  low   |  c1
1    | high   |  c2
1    |  low   |  c2
```

I tried with below group by clause but was returning the count of main types

Here is my query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count, Sub_Type, Main_Type FROM CHANGE GROUP BY Sub_Type, Main_Type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never showed us your query, but I am guessing that you grouped by the wrong column(s).  Just do a `GROUP BY` on the sub and main type columns, and select the count.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    Sub_Type,
    Main_Type
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Sub_Type,
    Main_Type
ORDER BY
    Main_Type,
    Sub_Type
```

Comment: In my query only `ORDER BY` part is missing i ran ur query tht z also returning same result

Comment: Hmm...do you have any whitespace characters leading or trailing in either type column?  This is the only thing which comes to mind.

Comment: No white spaces in column values

Comment: Please edit your question and show us a reproducible problem.  Your current question does not seem to be reproducible to me

Comment: @Emperor - are you ABSOLUTELY SURE you don't have white spaces? Not even leading or trailing? How did you check that?